# Can I change the Apple Watch simulator language?

Tags: localization, watchkit, apple-watch

Is it possible to change the Apple Watch simulator locale? I want to test the localization of my watch app. I can change language on an iPhone simulator, but the watch simulator is always in English. I can't find any language settings:

[image: Apple Watch Simulator Settings]
[image: Apple Watch Simulator Settings General (top)]
[image: Apple Watch Simulator Settings General (bot)]

Comment: Just a note on the bounty - a solution that will run just the app in a localised mode is fine. Currently even this doesn't seem possible.

Comment: You can use https://github.com/PGSSoft/AutoMate - it's a library for language and location automate testing

Comment: @xenteros except it's for iOS, not watchOS...

Comment: With Xcode 10.1 this seems to be possible from within the Watch app on a simulated iPhone / iPad. The problem is it will usually tell you that there's no connection to the Watch. I managed to set the language for a Watch a single time,  but wasn't able to reproduce it since.

Comment: @Koraktor, good news, we are one step further.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most certainly not possible neither via Watch Simulator UI nor iOS Simulator Watch app, but you can copy over values from iOS Simulator folder located in:

`<simulator_dev_folder>/data/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist`

to the same file in your Watch Simulator.

Plist keys to look for:

- `AppleLocale`
- `AppleLanguages`
- `AppleKeyboards`

Comment: In a iOS simulator you can change language in Settings > General > Language & Region > iPhone Language. The same way as you do it on a device.

Comment: I've changed language on the iOS sim and tried to do what you proposed. I opened `.GlobalPreferences.plist` in watchOS sim and, unfortunately, `AppleLocale` and `AppleLanguages` keys wasn't presented there. Anyway, your idea was great.

Comment: No worries, kelin, just copy them over from iOS plist to Watch plist ;) after relaunching the Watch simulator, your newly set values will be used.

Comment: did you tested your solution? Because I tried it again, copying all keys to the list and the watch simulator was still in English after the relaunching.

Comment: You might need to wait a while until the Watch sim is fully synced with the related iOS Simulator. Even after that, the values might be occasionally overwritten by the Simulator from time to time, but it seems to be quite stable for me.

Comment: I'm not going to test your ideas anymore. No time for that.

Comment: I've pasted you a screenshot with a proof with Watch Simulator switched to Arabic  https://i.imgur.com/we33dCW.png – there's no official way, only this plist injection procedure.

Comment: Which version of watchOS do you use? I was testing this on watchOS 5.1, Apple Watch 4.

Comment: Same one. Current Xcode 10.1 simulators. You should have your Watch simulator turned off to best prevent any preferences sweeping. As it's not officially supported, one probably needs to experiment, but I got it working on first attempt.

Comment: Can you try it with Russian?

Comment: Sure, no problem  https://imgur.com/4FyOvew and here's the `.GlobalPreferences.plist` file content: http://pasty.ml/401

Comment: It worked! You just need to wait couple of minutes before launching the simulator, also I launched it using Simulator App, not Xcode. A great upvote to you!

Answer (score 6):

You cannot change the Apple Watch simulator locale, but you can change the locale of your Watch App. I use this to test localization. To change your app locale, go edit the Watch App Scheme: Run->Options->Application Language - choose the language and re-run your Apple watch app.

Comment: @kelin did you ever get it working? Restarting Xcode doesn't seem to do the trick for me.

Comment: @Jordan, unfortunately no.

Comment: @ken what version of Xcode were you running? Trying to figure out why it's working for some and not others.

Comment: @Jordan I'm using XCode 7.3

Comment: Running `Version 11.2.1 (11B53)` and it stopped working for me.. I removed all simulators and set them up again, but didn't change anything..

Answer (score 3):

`Run|Options|Application Language`

Unfortunately it works only on Xcode 7.2, not on  Xcode 7.1. There is no other known possibility.

**EDIT**

There is a brand new library for language and locale automate testing. It's called `AutoMate`. The documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/PGSSoft/AutoMate).

Comment: Unfortunately I'm running Xcode 7.3 already. Unless that's what you meant instead of 7.1, it doesn't seem to be working. Restarts etc don't seem to fix the issue. Anything else I could try?

Comment: OK, to clarify - you're saying it works in 7.2 and is a regression in 7.3? Will only up vote if it actually works :-)

Comment: ... that framework you posted isn't going to work. UITests are not supported on watchOS yet.

Answer (score 2):

I post my comment for a more readable format.

Hope that can be a "viable" work around

- Create the different localization files: English, French, Spanish, Chinese…
- localize all elements here
- then, open the English files
- copy the content of the language you want to test after the present english text (that will supersede it).
- To come back to english, delete this added foreign text.

I tested, it works.

I just get an error log, without apparent consequence

*Watch Extension[3520:334638] [default] -[SPRemoteInterface _interfaceControllerClientIDForControllerID:]:2140: ComF: clientIdentifier for interfaceControllerID:DC00003 not found*

But that is good enough to test localization on simulator.

Removing the extra text clears the error.

Answer (score 2):

I improved this answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54883097/2519218

1. Change directory to your simulator devices. eg. /Users/$USER_NAME/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices
2. Detect your watch simulator. I used `ls -trl` command after build. eg. 046D5EDA-1808-4BE2-A16E-04DF0324B032
3. `plutil -convert xml1 ./046D5EDA-1808-4BE2-A16E-04DF0324B032/data/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist -o change_global.plist`
4. Edit change_global.plist AppLanguages's section you want to use by vim. I wanted to use ja, so it's like `<key>AppleLanguages</key> <array> <string>ja</string> </array>`.
5. Put change_global.plist to ./046D5EDA-1808-4BE2-A16E-04DF0324B032/data/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist. like `cp change_global.plist ./046D5EDA-1808-4BE2-A16E-04DF0324B032/data/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist` .
6. Restart simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like you can change the language in the watch simulator at this time. On the device, it's located in the iPhone Watch app under General -> Language & Region. However, on the iPhone simulator, there isn't even an option for the General section. This is all that shows up under the Watch app:

[image: iPhone Watch App]

Comment: in the current simulator the option appeared but when you try it says that "this device is not paired with this apple watch"

Comment: That may be a  work around
- Create all localization files: English, French, …
- in English files, append the content of the language you want to test after  english text.
- To come back to english, delete this added foreign text.

Et voila, turned around a critical miss of Watch simulator!
I tested, it works. Just get an error log, without apparent consequence
Watch Extension[3520:334638] [default] -[SPRemoteInterface _interfaceControllerClientIDForControllerID:]:2140: ComF: clientIdentifier for interfaceControllerID:DC00003 not found.

Removing the extra text clears the error.